# Variance of an estimator for a die roll yielding one

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

On page 180 of the textbook Givens and Hoeting, under the section 6.4.1, I am trying to understand the following lines:
Suppose we wish to estimate the probability that a die roll will yield a one. If we roll the die n times, we would expect to see about n/6 ones, and our point estimate of the true probability would be the proportion of the ones in the sample. The variance of this estimator is 5/36n if the die is fair.

How is the variance 5/36n? Isn't it a binomial distribution with p=1/6 and q=5/6 and variance is simply 5n/36 and mean is n/6 ?

Comment: The statistic they're talking about is $X/n$ where $X$ is the number of $1$'s in $n$ rolls.  You are talking about $X$.  So, divide your variance by $n^2$ and you get their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understood the question correctly now with the help of the user @saulpatz comment, I am looking for the variance of the sample mean and we can denote it by:

$$Y = \frac{X_1 + X_2 + X_2,...,X_n}{n} $$ and each of the $X_i$s is distributed according to a bernoulli distribution whose variance is $pq$.
$$Var(Y) = \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{1}^{n}Var(X_i) = \frac{npq}{n^2} = \frac{pq}{n} $$

For expectation,
$$ E(Y) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}^{n}E(X_i)=\frac{1}{n}\times n\times \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{6}$$ Since $X_i \sim Ber(\frac{1}{6}).$